# How to troubleshoot rx_tcp_udp_chksum_err

Tags: troubleshooting

Recently our Nagios started reported network interface errors on few servers and I have no idea how to identify what caused these errors.

I collected some information here and hope someone can provide some advice.

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:53:08:A6:EC
          inet addr:10.182.4.17  Bcast:10.182.7.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
          RX packets:164600148032 errors:67859 dropped:26955363 overruns:2 frame:67859
          TX packets:3498398714 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:73232469076775 (66.6 TiB)  TX bytes:2998456371714 (2.7 TiB)
          Interrupt:40


ethtool -i eth1

   driver: sfc
   version: 3.2
   firmware-version: 3.3.0.6298
   bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
   supports-statistics: yes
   supports-test: yes
   supports-eeprom-access: no
   supports-register-dump: yes
   supports-priv-flags: no

ethtool -S eth1

     NIC statistics:
     tx_bytes: 2998441377182
     tx_good_bytes: 2998441377182
     tx_bad_bytes: 0
     tx_packets: 3498277681
     tx_bad: 0
     tx_pause: 10
     tx_control: 10
     tx_unicast: 3469342716
     tx_multicast: 28924898
     tx_broadcast: 10067
     tx_lt64: 0
     tx_64: 10707489
     tx_65_to_127: 2090483055
     tx_128_to_255: 1016140
     tx_256_to_511: 536073713
     tx_512_to_1023: 1122081
     tx_1024_to_15xx: 517594725
     tx_15xx_to_jumbo: 341280478
     tx_gtjumbo: 0
     tx_collision: 0
     tx_single_collision: 0
     tx_multiple_collision: 0
     tx_excessive_collision: 0
     tx_deferred: 0
     tx_late_collision: 0
     tx_excessive_deferred: 0
     tx_non_tcpudp: 0
     tx_mac_src_error: 0
     tx_ip_src_error: 0
     tx_tso_bursts: 0
     tx_tso_long_headers: 0
     tx_tso_packets: 0
     tx_pushes: 997738192
     rx_bytes: 73230776458079
     rx_good_bytes: 73159089285734
     rx_bad_bytes: 71687172345
     rx_packets: 164596356458
     rx_good: 164410019215
     rx_bad: 67675
     rx_pause: 0
     rx_control: 0
     rx_unicast: 3862651550
     rx_multicast: 160533922396
     rx_broadcast: 13445269
     rx_lt64: 0
     rx_64: 29145974
     rx_65_to_127: 24196814809
     rx_128_to_255: 85333977542
     rx_256_to_511: 29573419148
     rx_512_to_1023: 10692885531
     rx_1024_to_15xx: 11810617170
     rx_15xx_to_jumbo: 2959496284
     rx_gtjumbo: 0
     rx_bad_lt64: 0
     rx_bad_64_to_15xx: 0
     rx_bad_15xx_to_jumbo: 0
     rx_bad_gtjumbo: 0
     rx_overflow: 2
     rx_missed: 0
     rx_false_carrier: 0
     rx_symbol_error: 0
     rx_align_error: 0
     rx_length_error: 0
     rx_internal_error: 0
     rx_nodesc_drop_cnt: 26955363
     rx_reset: 0
     rx_tobe_disc: 186269583
     rx_ip_hdr_chksum_err: 0
     rx_tcp_udp_chksum_err: 67646
     rx_mcast_mismatch: 3470220
     rx_frm_trunc: 0
     rx_nodesc_trunc: 0
```

SolarFlare user guide just says `rx_tcp_udp_chksum_err` Number of packets received with TCP/UDP checksum error.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you find solution? I have the same problem, changed modules, cables, NICs, ports...